# Ubuntu 11.10 not accepting password to change printers?

Tags: 11.10, printing, password, password-recovery

Ubuntu 11.10 not accepting root password to change printers.
Keeps saying password may be invalid.
Password works to unlock root user.

Answer (score 1):

Printers are not asking for "root PW".
Printers are asking for "standard user PW".
Saw a screen flash by when working something else.